# Content on page moves left when p5.js finishes preload

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I'm using p5.js to make an audio player. But the problem is that the elements on the page, which should be in the center of the page according to the css, always move to left a bit after the call to the `preload()` (the elements were in the center before the `preload()` returns).

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #fff;
            transition: background-color 3s ease-in-out;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        #music-player {
            max-width: 400px;
            padding: 30px;
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            text-align: center;
        }

        .control-icons {
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

            .control-icons i {
                opacity: 0.5;
                transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

                .control-icons i:hover {
                    opacity: 1;
                }

                .control-icons i.active {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="music-player">
        <div class="control-icons">
            <i class="fas fa-spinner" id="p5_loading" title="Loading..."></i>
            <i class="fas fa-play-circle" onclick="playAudio()" id="playButton" title="Play" style="display: none;"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-pause-circle" onclick="pauseAudio()" id="pauseButton" title="Pause" style="display: none;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const path = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('path');
        const encodedPath = encodeURIComponent(path).replace(/%20/g, "+");
        const apiUrl = './audio';

        let audio;

        function setup() {
        }

        function preload() {
            audio = loadSound(`${apiUrl}?path=${encodedPath}`, finishLoading, errorLoading);
        }

        function errorLoading(e) {
            console.error("Error Loading Audio: " + e);
        }

        function finishLoading() {
            if (audio.isLoaded()) {
                playButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
            }
        }

        function playAudio() {
            if (audio.isLoaded() && !audio.isPlaying()) {
                playButton.style.display = 'none';
                pauseButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                audio.play();
            }
        }

        function pauseAudio() {
            if (audio.isPlaying()) {
                playButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
                pauseButton.style.display = 'none';
                audio.pause();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what the cause is and how to make the elements stay in the center of the page?

Comment: Perhaps `playButton.style.display = 'inline-block'` is shifting elements around?  What if you temporarily prevent your buttons from hiding/showing, does the problem persist?

Comment: @James I tried by changing `<i class="fas fa-play-circle" onclick="playAudio()" id="playButton" title="Play" style="display: none;"></i>` to `<i class="fas fa-play-circle" onclick="playAudio()" id="playButton" title="Play"></i>` and deleting `<i class="fas fa-spinner" id="p5_loading" title="Loading..."></i>` and `playButton.style.display = 'inline-block';`. But the problem still persists.